# What the difference between providers DATANUCLEUS and DATANUCLEUS_2 in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo, datanucleus

Can anyone tell me the difference between theses two commands?

> persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database H2_IN_MEMORY
>
> persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS_2 --database H2_IN_MEMORY

What's dnucleus_2??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this part of the Roo Reference Documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-persistence.html

The relevant part of the page notes that ...

> Version 1 does not support JPA 2 and should only be used if you are intending to deploy to Google App Engine. Version 2 should be used if you are intending to deploy to VMforce cloud environments.

So, for AppEngine use DATANUCLEUS, and for anything that uses JPA 2 (including VMForce) use DATANUCLEUS_2.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the documentation for the --providers.